# What is suitable Oracle's DB XE version for practice ?, and errors in version 21c

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle21c

i have some problem with the Oracle DB XE version 21c.
i use it on my laptop to follow a data lab course in my campus
at first usage i try at the campus computer and works normally. but when i download
and install on my laptop (ofc for practice and homework), i encountered some problems 

like :

username should use "c##" prefix (i avoid using `_oracle_script=true`
as others recommend)

then i got problem when adding select permission to my account via system user,
like i wrote here :  `grant select on HR.EMPLOYEES to c##SI0x_xxx;`

and cmd throws error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`
 but when i creating an account + schema on my campus's computer it's worked without throws any error.

i also try to drop and re-create the user using system account but nothing worked.

for detail i put the version used on this case.
my laptop uses Oracle's DB Express Edition version 21c (21.3.0.0.0)
the campus computer uses an Oracle's DB version 10 (sorry i forgot to write exact version).
at the end i assuming the 21c version not have "HR.EMPLOYEE" table, then i need some help
to find best version to practice.
Thanks, and i'am have to say sorry if i did some mistakes and poor at english writing.

[UPDATE]
i ended to choose 10 or 11g later as my lecturer recommends.
when at version 21c i just getting more problem because this is the first time i use this program and also kinda busy to try it more.
also thanks to anyone who answer this
it's helpful to get some info to try it with newer version if needed.

Comment: You may use https://livesql.oracle.com or [Free Tier](https://developer.oracle.com/free/) that doesn't require any installation. In Free Tier you may create additional schemas and use as personal DB, because it is a pluggable DB. Oracle 10g is too old even for learning purposes, because it doesn't have some modern functionality

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 21cXE doesn't contain the HR schema, so you'll have to install it first. Because, `grant` you ran failed as that table (nor user) exists.

Have a look at [Installation of the Sample Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D)  document which contains more information.

---

Once you install `HR`, connect as `HR` (no need to use `SYSTEM` for that) and grant privileges to your newly created user.

Alternatively, why wouldn't you use HR schema directly? It is on your laptop, there's nothing you can spoil (and even if you did, just re-create it).

Comment: i'll try this method later, at first i'am new to this program (oracle db), then i following the lecturer's guide to do it and ran to much more problem (probably different version and device are used to do)